# Apple StoreKit 2: how can we test Family Sharing?

Tags: storekit, storekittest

I'm not a member of any Family in iCloud. I want to understand what happens when a user is subscribed through Family Sharing but also how to use StoreKit when the user is subscribed twice: as an individual who purchased the product and as a member of a family when the purchase is shared with him.

How can I test Family Sharing for an app offering a product with Family Sharing enabled? Is it possible to create a fake Family in App Store Connect and add testers to it?